# Can I change the return type based on a parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am unsure as to how to formulate my question, so bear with me if the question title looks incorrect to you.

```js
function uselessFunction(value: number): string | number {
    if (value > 5) {
        return "false"
    }
    return 2
}

const uselessVar1 = uselessFunction(1);
// type is `string | number`
// expected would be `number`

const uselessVar2 = uselessFunction(10);
// type is `string | number`
// expected would be `string`.
```

I know about `typeguard` concept, and how I could use it, but that's not my use-case.

```js
function isString(value: string | number): value is string {
    if (typeof value === "string") {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

if (isString(uselessVar1) {
    // uselessVar1 type is `string`.
}
```

I would like to know if it's possible for typescript to know if `uselessVar1` is either a `string` or a `number` immediatly after the return, and how could I achieve this.

Also, as to the `how` is interesting to me, I'd also like to know if it's a bad practice and why.

If you're more interested in the original use-case...

```js
/** 
 * Takes an input of type <T>[].
 * And returns bins of this list, of length binSize.
 * Example:
 *  
 * makeBinsFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3);
 * // [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
 * 
 * makeBinsFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3);
 * // [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7]]
 * 
 * makeBinsFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3, true);
 * // [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, undefined, undefined]]
*/
function makeBinsFromArray<T>(
  value: T[],
  binSize: number,
  fillLast?: boolean
): (T | (T | undefined))[][] {
  ...
}

const result = makeBinsFromArray([1, 2, 3], 2, true);
// expected type: (T | undefined)[][]

const result = makeBinsFromArray([1, 2, 3], 2);
// expected type: T[][];
```

Using this function, I want to know if I have a type `T[][]` or `(T | undefined)[][]` at compile time, depending on my `fillLast` argument.

Comment: I would simplify your question to just “Can I change the return type based on a parameter”

Comment: @kellys thanks for the input, i like it and its changed :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.

[Function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) are typically what you want here where you have different signature for each way that you want the function to be called.

```
function makeBinsFromArray<T>(
  value: T[],
  binSize: number,
  fillLast: true
): (T | undefined)[][]

function makeBinsFromArray<T>(
  value: T[],
  binSize: number,
  fillLast?: false
): T[][]

function makeBinsFromArray<T>(
  value: T[],
  binSize: number,
  fillLast?: boolean
): (T | (T | undefined))[][] {
  /// implementation
}

const resultA = makeBinsFromArray([1, 2, 3], 2, true);
// (T | undefined)[][]

const resultB = makeBinsFromArray([1, 2, 3], 2);
// T[][];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYGsCmAhGYDOAYgE5zICCxxqAngDwAqAfABQBQiiAbqgDYiYAXIgYBtALoAaDogBGeAMowAXkMRgQyWZmLTOwGL14AZVPijCoxAWwCUwlg0QAfROAAmmA2EzvbEiTY2UEhYBBQMHDwiUgoqWkZWGR5+NTEpGXkwJVVhDS0dPUQDI1NzAH5hYD58TDthdMDg8Gh4JDQsXAISMkpqemZ2ThSBBokirJy1fO1dGRKTMyhKuTg4XkxUMHrERxddp1cPLzxfW39xCUQAbxkAegfEGGQABw3kTDAoVDDtzmJMFAQMQkNcAL6IMyQsA0NhgoIQBDmRAA-AgXhQciIAC8EU60R6cX6LFEAEZJIgAEwUgDMUipFKsAlsAG42I9MAAPF6YaC+RBQGg8hyHNxgTzeM4BcQIpFQFGYNEY7A4vFRbqxPq0EnkhmIOkUyms9l3RBcnl89wCoVpaUsoA)

---

However, this isn't going to work:

```
function uselessFunction(value: number): string | number {}
const uselessVar1 = uselessFunction(1); // `number`
const uselessVar2 = uselessFunction(10); // `string`.
```

You can can change the return based on the *type* of a parameter, but this performs logic based on a value. And a number type cannot be mathematically compared to another number type in Typescript, so this can't work. `string | number` is the best you'll get here.

Well, [not impossible](https://itnext.io/implementing-arithmetic-within-typescripts-type-system-a1ef140a6f6f), but this path is not for the feint of heart. Nor, probably, a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
function foo<Param extends boolean>(param?: Param): Param extends false | undefined ? T[][] : (T | undefined)[][]
```

It is possible using a generic to “store” what the parameter is. Then in the return type annotation we use a conditional to get the correct return type.

I have left out the body and other parameters for brevity.